# Turn on an LED with dimming and stay on (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pwm

I want to start the LED gradually with dimming by using PWM.

And then once at a `ChangeDutyCycle(100)` I want it to remain on `GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)`.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

def dim():
    green = GPIO.PWM(led, 100)
    green.start(0)
    pause_time = 0.010

    for i in range(0, 100+1):
        green.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(pause_time)
    
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)

dim()
```

But with the script above it just turns off.

Is this possible?

Comment: How did you connect the LED? From the pin to ground? Or from VCC to the pin?

Comment: @mensi pin 9 (ground) and pin 11(17) on the Pi 3B+.